# Home Assistant, AppDaemon and Pytest - ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, pytest, python-import

I have a directory structure that looks like this:

```
appdaemon
  - apps
    - shared
      - __init__.py
      - common.py
    - __init__.py
    - code.py
  - tests
    - __init__.py
    - code_test.py
```

`code.py` imports `common.py` via:

`from shared import common`

This code runs just fine.

I'm trying to then run `code_test.py` via pytest, which looks like:

```
from appdaemon_testing.pytest import automation_fixture
from apps.code import Code
...
```

This doesn't work, I get an error:

```
ImportError while importing test module '/config/appdaemon/tests/code_test.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
/usr/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py:127: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
tests/code_test.py:8: in <module>
    from apps.code import Code
apps/code.py:3: in <module>
    from shared import common
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'shared'
```

How do I structure this so that the imports work within the test?
Also, more generally, what am I missing in terms of my understanding of this import model?

Comment: How exactly do you invoke the test?

Comment: Most likely you are missing what is written in the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time